# UIScrollView/UITextView scroll indicator insets issue with zero value

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

We're experiencing odd behavior when configuring `UIScrollView`'s `.scrollIndicatorInsets` property.

Specifically, when we set our `UITextView`'s `.scrollIndicatorInsets` to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)` the result is the first screen below (with the scroll indicators' topmost edge well below the top of the view's content insets). When setting to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(-0.01, 0, 0, 0)` the result is the second screen below (with the scroll indicators' topmost edge basically right where we'd expect if applying a zero value).

What is the cause of this bug? We have verified that it is not connected to the view's its super views' `.contentInset` properties.

**First Image, with flawed scroll indicator inset.**

[image: First image, with flawed scroll indicator inset.]

**Second image, with expected scroll indicator inset.**

[image: Second image, with expected scroll indicator inset.]

Comment: Are you sure about this? Here's what I get with a quick test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV6HU.png --- green uses default, yellow uses `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)` and cyan uses `UIEdgeInsetsMake(-0.01, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @DonMag completely sure. Might the existence of ```UINavigationBar``` have an impact? What else would introduce the odd behavior?

Comment: I suppose it could be related to the `UINavigationBar` ... can you put together a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your scroll view `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` property value as `.never` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets` property value as `false`. if you didn't set these properties the scroll indicator insets are will be automatically adjusted by the system.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Setting `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` had no effect and setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets` (which, according to Xcode 15, was deprecated in iOS 11) causes my scroll indicators to disappear.